# Salesforce Contact's Email Sends empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, send-email, sales-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have salescloud and marketing cloud integrated via connector.
If I do a salesforce send to a report, emails go through ok, and the tracking information goes back to salescloud:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w4Nb.jpg
Open tracking is detailed in the "Individual email results" section.

But, I don't see any records in "email sends" for any contact in the report:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj6gm.jpg

How can i have the info populated in that section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Email Sends** list will only populate with email sends made to individual contacts / leads. If it's added onto the page layout, you will see that **Send Marketing Cloud Email** link in addition to the **Unsubscribe** and **View Analytics** -- that is the link which allows you to send to an individual.

All sends to Reports / Campaigns / Salesforce Data Extensions will populate in the **Individual Email Results** related list, which can also be added to any Lead / Contact page layout.